# Automatically Compressing Published Files Into a .ZIP File

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I am currently using Teamcity to automatically build and publish our solution to a directory specified in the system.PublishProfile property (i.e. C:\Deployment Files).

Is it possible that after publishing TC will automatically .zip them into one file with a custom set file name?

Comment: You could use a [zip Task](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks). 
There is also an example in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419659.aspx (look for Figure 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define `Artifacts paths` inside `General Settings` tabs, you can set:

```
./out/Deploy => %BuildName%.zip
```

And, inside `Parameters`, you can specify the `BuildName` value.
This will produce a zipped artifact.